# HTTP Connection to a web server without port forwarding

Tags: reverse-proxy, port-forwarding

What are the possible ways of accessing a web server without setting up port forwarding? (or basically, no access to the router - so no DMZ). Reverse Proxy?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really provided many details, but I'll give it a shot.

A reverse proxy would have to run *on your gateway* to meet your requirements...otherwise, you would still need to set up port forwarding so that the proxy could reach your web server.

A VPN solution might be appropriate, depending on what you're trying to do. For example, I have various services running at my office that (a) I want access to from home and (b) I do not want to expose to the public.  So I connect from home to a VPN, effectively putting me "inside" the office network so I can access the services directly.

If you give us more details about exactly what you're trying to do we can probably provide a more appropriate answer.

Comment: My bad. Here you go - What I intend to achieve is that I make a user install a web server but I dont want the user to go into the complexities port forwarding. And a second user should be able to access the web server. Strange, but yea. Know of any existing ideas like this? I have heard NAT Traversal and Proxy servers can do such stuff - any existing projects like this?